# Child ignores changes to Parent's transform position during runtime. How to fix?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position, transform, instance

I have spheres being instantiated as children of a GameObject. I want these spheres to follow the Position of the GameObject.

The trouble is, these spheres stubbornly stay in the place they were spawned in, and refuse to change their position upon any Transform position changes in Inspector during runtime.

```
spheres = new GameObject[mesh.vertexCount]; //create gameobject array, size of mesh vertex count

for (int i = 0; i < mesh.vertexCount; i++)
{
    matrices1pos[i] = matrices1[i].position;
    spheres[i] = Instantiate(spherePrefab, matrices1[i].position, Quaternion.identity);
    spheres[i].transform.SetParent(GO2.transform);
}
```

I even tried adding code:

`spheres[i].transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;`

but that doesn't make the spheres respond to parent's position changes either.

By the way, the location the Spheres spawn in is the location of the GameObject (called `MeshChanger`) the script runs on. Changing the position of `MeshChanger` transform during runtime has no effect either.

edit: Solved! see answer below

Comment: How do you set `GO2`? Are you sure that it's not a reference to a prefab?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not entirely sure what you mean as I'm newbie. In `MeshChanger.cs` I have `public GO2 GO2;` before any functions, and for gameobject `GO2` I simply have script GO2.cs attached which says `public Transform Transform { get; set; }`

Comment: I mean, do you set the value of `GO2` using the inspector? If so, make sure you are referring to a GO2 that is on a game object that is in the scene hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to use **local**Position. =]

```
spheres[i].transform.SetParent(GO2.transform);
spheres[i].transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(matrices1pos[i], matrices2[i].position, t);
```